# Desestruturamento de Arrays

Tags: javascript

Tô perdido, onde está a lógica do código?

```js
const contatos = [
    {
        nome: 'Alex Júnior',
        numero: '1234-5678'
    },
    {
        nome: 'Carolina Moya',
        numero: '1234-6789'
    },
    {
        nome: 'Fernando Jorge',
        numero: '12345-5567'
    }
];
const [, Carol] = contatos; // Não entendi esse trecho
function mostraNumero({numero}){
    console.log(numero)
}
mostraNumero(Carol);
```

Qual é o objetivo do trecho const [, Carol] = contatos, eu não consegui entender?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isso se chama [Atribuição via desestruturação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Atribuicao_via_desestruturacao). Nesse caso, o trecho de código declara a variável Carol, que receberá a segunda posição do array que foi passado, por isso a notação `[, Carol]`. Isso é similar a fazer: `const Carol = contatos[1]`.

Vale lembrar que essa é uma adição do ES6, logo pode não estar disponível em todos os navegadores.

EDIT: Fazendo mais uma adição, para ficar ainda mais claro. No exemplo que você colocou, poderíamos fazer também:

```
const contatos = [
    {
        nome: 'Alex Júnior',
        numero: '1234-5678'
    },
    {
        nome: 'Carolina Moya',
        numero: '1234-6789'
    },
    {
        nome: 'Fernando Jorge',
        numero: '12345-5567'
    }
];
const [Alex , Carol] = contatos; // Não entendi esse trecho
function mostraNumero({numero}){
    console.log(numero)
}
mostraNumero(Carol);
mostraNumero(Alex);
```

Que seria equivalente a fazer:

```
const Alex = contatos[0];
const Carol = contatos[1];
```